# Dumping ipa file on iOS 10.2

Tags: ios, dumping

Is there a way to dump .ipa file on iOS 10.2 (jailbroken) for future reverse-engineering? Tried to use Clutch, it doesn't dump the app. Just exits with

```
2017-03-13 23:17:24.702 Clutch[2195:100953] application <NSOperationQueue: 0x10bf909b0>{name = 'NSOperationQueue 0x10bf909b0'}
2017-03-13 23:17:24.702 Clutch[2195:100919] application <NSOperationQueue: 0x10bf0c9d0>{name = 'NSOperationQueue 0x10bf0c9d0'}
```

errors.

Answer (score 1):

So Installing ipainstaller through Cydia and then dumping with command (through ssh)

```
ipainstaller -b com.example.targetapp -o /tmp/example.ipa
```

does the work